# Is it advisable to always click on "safely remove drive" for an external SSD drive before "closing the laptop lid" (going into standby/suspend mode)?

Tags: suspend, ssd, usb-drive

… if so, why?

---

- The drive (in my case) **contains files only** (backup files, media, ... );
- *It is **not** a boot drive, **nor** does it contain a swap partition or any installations or programs.*

---

I can imagine three usage scenarios here (sorted by presumed "riskiness"):

1. drive is safely removed, then physically unplugged, prior to closing the laptop lid; only once system has then awoken after its sleep is the drive physically re-connected again
2. system is suspended (**without** prior "safe removal" of the drive), drive **remains physically plugged-in throughout** and beyond waking from suspend
3. system is suspended (**without** prior "safe removal" of the drive), **drive is physically unplugged during suspend** and remains unplugged when waking from suspend

---

Related link(s):

- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-removedrive.html.en

Comment: (This is about the [SanDisk Extreme Portable External SSD](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20670/~/sandisk-extreme-portable-ssd-support-information) formatted as ext4.)

Comment: Is the external SSD your boot drive? Does it contain swap? Why the need to disconnect? Option #2 looks like the only reasonable choice out of the three.

Comment: @heynnema No, not a boot drive nor swap. **Just data and media** (no installations/programs).

Comment: Just leave it connected, and suspend the computer at will. Unmount the drive, and use safe removal if you really need to disconnect the drive for some reason.

Comment: @heynnema say I suspend ("close the lid") with the (external) ssd connected, then I unplug it in suspended state and "open the lid" again: would that be a problem - or is Ubuntu taking care of "all eventualities" ?

Comment: I would say that your process is asking for a corrupted external SSD. Follow the procedure in my previous comment... IF you REALLY need to disconnect it. Eject and then Safe Removal.

Answer (score 0):

Case three from the above could result in data loss. Therefore, ejecting the USB drive device before suspension is suggested.